# Add multiple small git repo's to a larger repository

Tags: python, git

I made a wrapper project using GitPython that works with git repositories. The tests I wrote use some small repositories I created. Is there any way to add these repositories and their .git files to my main repo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out submodules: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules

They allow you to embed one git repo in another.